# Difficult aggregation in R, grouping team basketball stats

Tags: r

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions on this. Here is a shortened example of the dataframe I am working with.

```
boxscore_stats = structure(list(game_id = c(157046L, 157046L, 157046L, 157046L, 
157046L, 157046L, 157046L, 157046L, 157046L, 157046L, 157046L, 
157046L, 157046L, 157046L, 157046L, 157046L, 157046L, 157046L, 
159151L, 159151L, 159151L, 159151L, 159151L, 159151L, 159151L, 
159151L, 159151L, 159151L, 159151L, 159151L, 159151L, 159151L, 
159151L, 159151L, 159151L, 159151L, 159151L, 159151L, 159151L, 
159151L), team_id = c(116975, 116975, 116975, 116975, 116975, 
116975, 116975, 116975, 116975, 120310, 120310, 120310, 120310, 
120310, 120310, 120310, 120310, 120310, 121910, 121910, 121910, 
121910, 121910, 121910, 121910, 121910, 121910, 121910, 122072, 
122072, 122072, 122072, 122072, 122072, 122072, 122072, 122072, 
122072, 122072, 122072), minutes_played = c(18.76, 14.63, 8, 
16.69, 24.62, 32, 12.79, 5.28, 3.22, 24.35, 10.18, 20.65, 9.59, 
25.08, 14.12, 17.46, 23.15, 15.43, 22.84, 19.27, 21.31, 6.41, 
17.57, 17.4, 17.29, 7.22, 12.09, 17.25, 2.28, 16.87, 6.6, 19.73, 
6.31, 13.25, 26.25, 6.08, 28.71, 11.2, 17.54, 5.17), fieldGoalsMade = c(1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 7L, 
1L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 
1L, 11L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L), fieldGoalAttempts = c(8L, 6L, 7L, 
2L, 9L, 16L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 12L, 4L, 12L, 3L, 11L, 4L, 9L, 13L, 
6L, 12L, 10L, 14L, 2L, 6L, 11L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 10L, 
2L, 3L, 21L, 3L, 17L, 4L, 9L, 2L)), .Names = c("game_id", "team_id", 
"minutes_played", "fieldGoalsMade", "fieldGoalAttempts"), row.names = c(NA, 
40L), class = "data.frame")


head(boxscore_stats)

   game_id team_id minutes_played fieldGoalsMade fieldGoalAttempts
1   157046  116975          18.76              1                 8
2   157046  116975          14.63              1                 6
3   157046  116975           8.00              4                 7
4   157046  116975          16.69              1                 2
5   157046  116975          24.62              2                 9
6   157046  116975          32.00              7                16
7   157046  116975          12.79              1                 3
8   157046  116975           5.28              1                 1
9   157046  116975           3.22              1                 2
10  157046  120310          24.35              4                12
11  157046  120310          10.18              0                 4
12  157046  120310          20.65              3                12
13  157046  120310           9.59              1                 3
14  157046  120310          25.08              3                11
15  157046  120310          14.12              0                 4
16  157046  120310          17.46              6                 9
17  157046  120310          23.15              7                13
18  157046  120310          15.43              1                 6
19  159151  121910          22.84              7                12
20  159151  121910          19.27              4                10
21  159151  121910          21.31              5                14
22  159151  121910           6.41              1                 2
23  159151  121910          17.57              2                 6
24  159151  121910          17.40              6                11
25  159151  121910          17.29              2                 6
26  159151  121910           7.22              0                 2
27  159151  121910          12.09              1                 2
28  159151  121910          17.25              3                 6
29  159151  122072           2.28              0                 0
30  159151  122072          16.87              1                 5
31  159151  122072           6.60              1                 3
32  159151  122072          19.73              3                10
33  159151  122072           6.31              0                 2
34  159151  122072          13.25              1                 3
35  159151  122072          26.25             11                21
36  159151  122072           6.08              2                 3
37  159151  122072          28.71              5                17
38  159151  122072          11.20              1                 4
39  159151  122072          17.54              2                 9
40  159151  122072           5.17              1                 2
```

The important things to note about this dataframe is that each game_id corresponds with two team_ids, for the two teams that played in the game. Each game_id is unique to one game of basketball. Each row corresponds with the stats for a player on the team_ids team in that game. The example above has only two games / 4 teams / 40 players, but my full dataframe has hundreds of games, which each team_id showing up many times.

My first aggregation, which I was able to do, was to aggregate everything by team_id. This code got the job done for me for the first aggregation:

```
boxscore_stats_aggregated = aggregate(boxscore_stats, by = list(boxscore_stats[, 2]), FUN = sum)
```

which was fairly straightforward. For any team_id, I had aggregated all of their minutes played, all of their fieldGoalsMade, etc. For my next aggregation though, I need to aggregate by team_id again but instead of aggregating a team by their own rows / stats, instead I need to aggregate the rows / stats of their opponents. This answers the question "For any team, how many fieldsGoalsMade did they allow in total to opponents, etc." So in this case, for team_id = 116975, I would want to aggregate all the rows with team_id 120310. Of course next time team_id 116975 appears in my dataframe in a new game, it is likely that they are playing a different opponent, so this aggregation is not as simple as aggregating by team_id 120310.

I think I should be able to use the relationship between the two team_ids being unique to the unique game_ids to make this aggregation possible, but I am struggling with how it could be implemented.

Thanks!

Comment: I could post some reproducible code if that would help as well

Comment: Yeah, I think a reproducible example would be good.

Comment: added dput() of the boxscore_stats dataframe first 40 rows

Comment: @majom please don't add tags per your suggested solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Here is approach using data.table:

(1) Read in the data:

```
# Load package
library(data.table)

# Load your data
boxscore_stats <- fread("row game_id team_id minutes_played fieldGoalsMade fieldGoalAttempts
1   157046  116975          18.76              1                 8
           2   157046  116975          14.63              1                 6
           3   157046  116975           8.00              4                 7
           4   157046  116975          16.69              1                 2
           5   157046  116975          24.62              2                 9
           6   157046  116975          32.00              7                16
           7   157046  116975          12.79              1                 3
           8   157046  116975           5.28              1                 1
           9   157046  116975           3.22              1                 2
           10  157046  120310          24.35              4                12
           11  157046  120310          10.18              0                 4
           12  157046  120310          20.65              3                12
           13  157046  120310           9.59              1                 3
           14  157046  120310          25.08              3                11
           15  157046  120310          14.12              0                 4
           16  157046  120310          17.46              6                 9
           17  157046  120310          23.15              7                13
           18  157046  120310          15.43              1                 6
           19  159151  121910          22.84              7                12
           20  159151  121910          19.27              4                10
           21  159151  121910          21.31              5                14
           22  159151  121910           6.41              1                 2
           23  159151  121910          17.57              2                 6
           24  159151  121910          17.40              6                11
           25  159151  121910          17.29              2                 6
           26  159151  121910           7.22              0                 2
           27  159151  121910          12.09              1                 2
           28  159151  121910          17.25              3                 6
           29  159151  122072           2.28              0                 0
           30  159151  122072          16.87              1                 5
           31  159151  122072           6.60              1                 3
           32  159151  122072          19.73              3                10
           33  159151  122072           6.31              0                 2
           34  159151  122072          13.25              1                 3
           35  159151  122072          26.25             11                21
           36  159151  122072           6.08              2                 3
           37  159151  122072          28.71              5                17
           38  159151  122072          11.20              1                 4
           39  159151  122072          17.54              2                 9
           40  159151  122072           5.17              1                 2
           ")
```

(2) Proceed with the actual calculations:

```
# Aggregate on team-and game level (data.table style)
boxscore_stats_aggregated  <-  boxscore_stats[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = list(game_id, team_id)] 

# Match EVERY team to each opponent, i.e. still two rows per game
# but columns for opponent's performance added.
# Some teams drops out in the dummy data as they opponent data was missing.
merge(boxscore_stats_aggregated, boxscore_stats_aggregated, 
      by="game_id", suffixes = c("", ".opponent"))[team_id!=team_id.opponent,]
```

`output` looks like that:

```
# > output
#    game_id team_id row minutes_played fieldGoalsMade fieldGoalAttempts team_id.opponent row.opponent minutes_played.opponent fieldGoalsMade.opponent fieldGoalAttempts.opponent
# 1: 1413414  116975  45         135.99             19                54           120310          126                  160.01                      25                         74
# 2: 1413414  120310 126         160.01             25                74           116975           45                  135.99                      19                         54
```

Comment: this looks promising, let me run on my larger dataset and see if it comes back as well as the example here. ofcourse, thank you

Comment: im not too familiar with the data.table class, but it seems that the code only works if my dataframe is created using the fread() function. when loaded as an ordinary dataframe, the line of code creating boxscore_stats_aggregated returns an error for unused argument (by = team_id)

Comment: Yup. If you work with larger data, data.table is the way to go. See 1000s of stackoverflow posts on this.

Comment: @majom **merge** with itself is the right approach, but aggregating on the team level beforehand will lead to wrong results if he adds more games to the dataset. I'm thinking about this: boxscore_stats_aggregated  <-  boxscore_stats[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = c('team_id','game_id')]

Answer (score 1):

And just in case, for OP to consider or future readers below is a base R version with `merge()` for side by side aggregates of team and opposition by `game_id`. A staging temp col, `gamecount`, is needed.

```
# TEAM AGGREGATION
aggdf <- aggregate(.~game_id + team_id, boxscore_stats, FUN = sum)

# GAME COUNT BY TEAM (TEMP COL USED FOR MERGE/FILTER)
aggdf$gamecount <- sapply(1:nrow(aggdf), function(i) 
                          sum(aggdf[1:i, c("game_id")] == aggdf$game_id[i]))    
# MERGE AND FILTER
mdf <- merge(aggdf, aggdf, by="game_id")
mdf <- mdf[mdf$team_id.x != mdf$team_id.y & mdf$gamecount.x == 1,]
mdf$gamecount.x <- mdf$gamecount.y <- NULL

# RENAME COL AND ROW NAMES
names(mdf)[grepl("\\.x", names(mdf))] <- gsub("\\.x", "", 
                                              names(mdf)[grepl("\\.x", names(mdf))])
names(mdf)[grepl("\\.y", names(mdf))] <- gsub("\\.y", ".opp", 
                                              names(mdf)[grepl("\\.y", names(mdf))])
rownames(mdf) <- 1:nrow(mdf)

#   game_id team_id minutes_played fieldGoalsMade fieldGoalAttempts team_id.opp
# 1  157046  116975         135.99             19                54      120310
# 2  159151  121910         158.65             31                71      122072
#   minutes_played.opp fieldGoalsMade.opp fieldGoalAttempts.opp
# 1             160.01                 25                    74
# 2             159.99                 28                    79
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to isolate single team_ids, I would use the dplyr package.

For example if you wanted to know % of field goals per team I would write something like:

```
boxscore_stats %>% 
     group_by(team_id) %>% 
     summarize(perc_fg = sum(fieldGoalsMade)/sum(fieldGoalAttempts))
```

This would give you a new `data.frame` aggregated by team `ID`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with dplyr but it seems really useful given how often I see it as a useful solution to problems posted on stackoverflow. however i tried to run that snippet and got an error: expecting a single value.

Comment: My apologies: `boxscore_stats %>% group_by(team_id) %>% summarize(n = sum(fieldGoalsMade)/ sum(fieldGoalAttempts))`