# R dataframe - using common value in one column to find values in another column

Tags: r

Sorry I couldn't come up with a better name for the title, I am struggling very much with explaining the problem at hand with words so let me show an example with a dataframe instead.

```
dput(DF)

structure(list(game_id = c(162044, 162044, 162044, 162044, 162044, 
162044, 162044, 162044, 162044, 162044, 162044, 162044, 162044, 
162044, 162044, 166807, 166807, 166807, 166807, 166807, 166807, 
166807, 166807, 166807, 166807, 166807, 166807, 166807, 166807, 
166807, 166807, 166807, 166807, 166807, 167948, 167948, 167948, 
167948, 167948, 167948, 167948, 167948, 167948, 167948, 167948, 
167948, 167948, 167948, 167948, 167948), team_id = c(108738, 
108738, 108738, 108738, 108738, 108738, 108738, 126351, 126351, 
126351, 126351, 126351, 126351, 126351, 126351, 54161, 54161, 
54161, 54161, 54161, 54161, 54161, 54161, 133418, 133418, 133418, 
133418, 133418, 133418, 133418, 133418, 133418, 54161, 54161, 
54161, 54161, 54161, 54161, 54161, 54161, 54161, 135796, 135796, 
135796, 135796, 135796, 135796, 135796, 135796, 135796)), .Names = c("game_id", 
"team_id"), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")  


head(DF)

   game_id team_id
1   162044  108738
2   162044  108738
3   162044  108738
4   162044  108738
5   162044  108738
6   162044  108738
7   162044  108738
8   162044  126351
9   162044  126351
10  162044  126351
11  162044  126351
12  162044  126351
13  162044  126351
14  162044  126351
15  162044  126351
16  166807   54161
17  166807   54161
18  166807   54161
19  166807   54161
20  166807   54161
21  166807   54161
22  166807   54161
23  166807   54161
24  166807  133418
25  166807  133418
26  166807  133418
27  166807  133418
28  166807  133418
29  166807  133418
30  166807  133418
31  166807  133418
32  166807  133418
33  166807   54161
34  166807   54161
35  167948   54161
36  167948   54161
37  167948   54161
38  167948   54161
39  167948   54161
40  167948   54161
41  167948   54161
42  167948  135796
43  167948  135796
44  167948  135796
45  167948  135796
46  167948  135796
47  167948  135796
48  167948  135796
49  167948  135796
50  167948  135796
```

This is the dataframe I am working with. Of importance is the fact that, for each game_id, there are two team_ids. If it helps with the problem, the game_ids are all sorted, and the team_ids could be grouped so that for each game_id, all instances of the first team_id appear, then all instances of the second team_id appear (this is currently not the case, as you can see in rows 33 and 34). I need to create a third column, called team2_id, where in this column are the other team_ids corresponding to the game_id. Example of desired output is below:

```
head(DF)

   game_id team_id team2_id
1   162044  108738   126351
2   162044  108738   126351
3   162044  108738   126351
4   162044  108738   126351
5   162044  108738   126351
6   162044  108738   126351
7   162044  108738   126351
8   162044  126351   108738   
9   162044  126351   108738
10  162044  126351   108738
11  162044  126351   108738
12  162044  126351   108738
13  162044  126351   108738
14  162044  126351   108738
15  162044  126351   108738
16  166807   54161   133418 
17  166807   54161   133418
18  166807   54161   133418
19  166807   54161   133418
20  166807   54161   133418
21  166807   54161   133418
22  166807   54161   133418
23  166807   54161   133418
24  166807  133418    54161   
25  166807  133418    54161
26  166807  133418    54161
27  166807  133418    54161
28  166807  133418    54161
29  166807  133418    54161
30  166807  133418    54161
31  166807  133418    54161
32  166807  133418    54161
33  166807   54161   133418
34  166807   54161   133418
35  167948   54161   135796
36  167948   54161   135796
37  167948   54161   135796
38  167948   54161   135796
39  167948   54161   135796
40  167948   54161   135796
41  167948   54161   135796
42  167948  135796    54161  
43  167948  135796    54161
44  167948  135796    54161
45  167948  135796    54161
46  167948  135796    54161
47  167948  135796    54161
48  167948  135796    54161
49  167948  135796    54161
50  167948  135796    54161
```

At first glance, I didn't think I would struggle with this type of data manipulation, however I am unfortunately finding this to be fairly difficult. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: Do you need the rows to be duplicated?

Comment: the rows come duplicated in the dataframe, yes. the dataframe corresponds to a basketball game, and each row corresponds to a specific player (so for any given game and team, there's 8-10 players that played)

Comment: Allright, that can be implemented with a join then. NB that your desired output misses the information to wich team a specific player belonged; my solution contains this info. If you don't want it, simply drop the column `team_id` and rename the columns `team1_id` and `team2_id` as needed.

Comment: You have asked this before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834402/difficult-aggregation-in-r-grouping-team-basketball-stats/

Comment: @majom provided you with the solution: `merge(boxscore_stats_aggregated, boxscore_stats_aggregated, by="game_id", suffixes = c("", ".opponent"))`

Comment: Please **try to learn from the answers SO provides you with**.

Comment: dang yes, i do recall asking this before. iirc, this solution removed many games from my dataframe for some reason, and i put this issue on the side as I worked on other parts of my code. apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using `tidyr` and `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
teams <- DF %>%
  group_by(game_id, team_id) %>% # For every game_id and team_id
  summarise() %>% # Create one row
  # Grouping is now for every game_id
  mutate(team_number = paste0("team", row_number(), "_id")) %>% # generate the to-be column name of this team_id
  spread(team_number, team_id) # Spread the column names to create the new columns
# Now join the team data to the original DF:
res <- DF %>%
  left_join(teams, by = "game_id")
```

`res` will now have the same columns as `DF` plus two more columns, `team1_id` and `team2_id` containing the `team_id` of the first resp. second team in the game as it appears in the data. It will also have the column `team_id` wich is equal to either `team1_id` or `team2_id` depending on which team the actual player belonged to.

Fun fact: If a `game_id` has more than two `team_id`s the code will gracefully create new columns `team3_id`, `team4_id`, etc. as needed.

Comment: i guess this is a good opportunity to install dplyr. I see it suggested often as a solution, is it a very good package?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can quickly get used to the notation and do data-wrangling tasks really quickly. For the same syntax with greater performance, there is also the new package `dtplyr`, a fusion of `dplyr` and `data.table`. `tidyr` is a similar package suitable for reshaping your data and revalueing (notably, `spread`, `gather`, `fill` and `replace_na` are very useful functions of `tidyr`)